# Using JSON/AJAX to pass dynamic information and return two header types

Tags: php, ajax, json, header, combinations

#### Background

I have an application which I am updating.  On other pages, I use a link to run a php script and return a `header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");` to print a document to MS Word.  Normally, these links dynamically generate the content on the fly.  In my current implementation scenario, I am attempting to use jQuery functions to display the content, and then have the document return information using JSON back to the current page. The general process which I am attempting to acheive is `1) user clicks link, 2) generate the letter and then 3) return a message to the original page with something similar to 'success'`.  My AJAX/JSON function works correctly, but I am receiving a `PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output...` and my link is not working.  Can someone help guide me how I can combine two header types in the PHP script dynamically?

#### Code Implementation

```
<?php
$query_letters = "....";
try {
    $letters = $customer->runQuery($query_letters);
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    foreach($letters as $letter) {
    $filename = "Letter_". $letter['id'].".doc";
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=" . $filename);
    echo $letters[0]['letter'];}
  } catch (Exception $e) {echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();}

$message=array('message' => "Congratulations!",'link' => $type);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($message); 
?>
```

#### Edit

I was thinking about possibly using javascript to call an iframe to run the php code, which in theory would also get the end result.  It should be pointed out that in order to acheive my goal, I do not necessarily need to use ajax to run my php script.  I just need to `create a link which prints a ms-word document on the fly`.

Comment: You can not do that. Once a script outputs anything, you can not set another header anymore. Which makes totally sense, a Word document != json. You can, however, create a scenario in which only a failure returns a json. When the script is successfull, the user will get a word-document, which in itself is a success message...

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly How would I change my ajax function to solely generate the ms-word document in that case, without returning any information? because if thats the case then I can use a different ajax function to actually display the notification of the congratulations message?

Comment: You could do it in two steps: first check to see if you can actually output your file (is everything you need available on the server and so on) and return a JSON answer to that. Depending on the return you can trigger a second AJAX-call to actually output the file.